# Is growing bamboo at home considered inauspicious?

Tags: belief, tradition, plants

Are there any scriptures or traditional systems around growing bamboo plants in a pot in the house? I heard from one of my elders but the elder was not certain, and hence would like to know more about it.

Comment: In my childhood I hv heard from my elders (and it is also a local belief I think)  that ghosts live in bamboo trees... :D

Comment: @Rickross Oh, I had heard of that only with tamarind trees, this is good to know, thanks. And do they mean trees (like tall ones) or even tiny 1-foot long plants?

Comment: I hv heard the same about Neem trees too ... When they said that abt the bamboo tress they would hv meant the usual long trees and not the bonsai ones..